# Utilizar un GridView

Tags: android-studio

Veran, estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual tengo un TextView y un GridView con una serie del elementos sacados de un vector. Cuando elijo algo del GridView, este se copia en el TextView.

Codigo de activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.pcx.celda.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seleccion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ABD8F9"
        android:text="Nombre"
        android:textColor="#000066" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#328DF9"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Codigo del MainActivity:

```
package com.example.pcx.celda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    public String[] provincias= {"Almería", "Cádiz", "Córdoba", "Granada", "Huelva", "Jaen", "Malaga", "Sevilla"};

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayAdapter adaptador=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,provincias);
        GridView grid=findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(adaptador);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
        TextView selection= findViewById(R.id.seleccion);
        selection.setText(provincias[position]);
    }
}
```

Pero algo falla. Cuando miro ejemplos, parece que en vez de "support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item" deberia poner un apunte a un fichero xml (en el ejemplo lo llaman "celda.xml"), pero no tengo ni idea de donde sale ese fichero.

Comment: Es facil que ese celda.xml sea un layout que ha definido para dar formato a la celda simplemente. Que error te da???

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano ¿Has dicho layout? ¿Te refieres a que el fichero "celda.xml" deberia estar en la carpeta  de mismo nombre (la de activity_main.xml)?

Comment: si, en la carpeta res/layout/

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Vale. Lo he probado y así es, puedo editar los iconos del GridView con ese fichero. Gracias por aclararlo.

Comment: Tienes definido   android:layout_height="match_parent" en tu TextView, por lo tanto lo que se encuentre abajo no se visualizara. La carga del String array en tu Grid es correcta. @MiguelAlparez

Answer (score 0):

Parece que lo he solucionado. El error en realidad residia en que el textView tapaba al GridView y por eso no veia los objetos. Al lograr colocarlos reduciendo su ancho, ahora si veo los iconos de los nombres y funcionan tal y como queria.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que el `TextView` tiene definida la propiedad:

```
<TextView
    ....
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
```

Teniendo definido: `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, lo cual provocará que esta vista cubra toda la pantalla por lo tanto no se visualizarán los elementos inferiores, en este caso el Grid.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes 2 opciones para corregir esto:

Puedes definir una altura fija, por ejemplo.

```
  android:layout_height="200dp"
```

O puedes por ejemplo asignar un peso de 1 a cada elemento para que el espacio sea uniforme:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/seleccion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ABD8F9"
    android:text="Nombre"
    android:textColor="#000066"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#328DF9"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Se vería de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]